# The Kernel of an Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the kernel of the following homomorphism.

$\Phi: \mathbb{Z}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$

where

$\Phi(x,y,u,v) = (x+2y+u,y-3v)$

My first try was to solve the equations

$x+2y+u= 0$ and $y-3v=0$

But I don't really come to any conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct idea. In particular, we can solve these equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ to get
$$
x = -u - 6v, \quad
y = 3v.
$$
Conclude that the kernel of the homomorphism is given by
$$
\{(-u-6v,3v,u,v): u,v \in \Bbb Z\}.
$$

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. In addition, can you conclude that the kernel is isomorphic with $Z^2$?

Comment: @miaa2021 Yes, you can

Comment: How would you do that? By using the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @miaa2021 Show that the map $\phi:\Bbb Z^2 \to K$ given by
$$
\phi(u,v) = (-u - 6v,3v,u,v)
$$
is an isomorphism